# Netbeans:Action event method is not defined in fxml

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

[I have 2 buttons ,when click on JFXButton 'inscrire', anchorPane Login bring to Front  if click on Login anchorPane SignUp bring to Front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIWGf.png)

My prblem is NetBeans invokes an exception that #handleButtonAction  method Controller is not defined on root component.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="489.0" prefWidth="778.0" style="-fx-background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0,0);" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane layoutY="34.0" prefHeight="438.0" prefWidth="778.0" style="-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-border-radius: 5em;">
         <children>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="PaneInscrire" layoutX="465.0" prefHeight="444.0" prefWidth="313.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff;">
               <children>
                  <JFXTextField layoutX="69.0" layoutY="118.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="189.0" promptText="id" unFocusColor="#4d4d4d" />
                  <JFXTextField layoutX="68.0" layoutY="170.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="189.0" promptText="Nom et Prenom" />
                  <JFXTextField layoutX="68.0" layoutY="216.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="189.0" promptText="Email" />
                  <JFXTextField layoutX="68.0" layoutY="260.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="189.0" promptText="Ville" />
                  <JFXTextField layoutX="68.0" layoutY="307.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="189.0" promptText="MotdePass" />
                  <JFXButton contentDisplay="CENTER" graphicTextGap="7.0" layoutX="106.0" layoutY="373.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="114.0" style="-fx-background-color: #5316F5;" text="inscrire" textFill="WHITE" />
                  <Label layoutX="66.0" layoutY="32.0" prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="196.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffgfg;" text="Inscruption" textFill="#5316f5">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="38.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
            <JFXButton fx:id="inscrire" layoutY="177.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="84.0" text="Inscrire" textFill="#5316f5" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="sign" layoutY="222.0" onAction="#handleButtonAction" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="84.0" text="Login" textFill="#5316f5" />
            <AnchorPane fx:id="PaneSign" layoutX="465.0" prefHeight="444.0" prefWidth="313.0" style="-fx-background-color: #FFFFFF; -fx-background-radius: 5em;">
               <children>
                  <JFXPasswordField layoutX="55.0" layoutY="233.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="233.0" promptText="MotPass" />
                  <JFXButton contentDisplay="CENTER" graphicTextGap="7.0" layoutX="106.0" layoutY="344.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="131.0" style="-fx-background-color: #5316F5;" text="SignIn" textFill="WHITE" />
                  <JFXTextField layoutX="55.0" layoutY="170.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="233.0" promptText="Username" />
                  <Label layoutX="100.0" layoutY="37.0" prefHeight="96.0" prefWidth="144.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffgfg;" text="Login" textFill="#5316f5">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="44.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
```

Comment: How do you load this FXML ? Do you set a controller to this FXML ?

Comment: Depending on how you load the fxml the only problem here is Netbeans complaining. You can simply ignore this if you set the controller instance for the `FXMLLoader` before loading the fxml.

Comment: As @fabian said ,id depends on loading method ,you can set your controller in your `FXMLLoader` `fxmlloaderName.setController(controllername)`  in your java code,or by adding `<AnchorPane ... fx:controller="package.controller_name">` in your fxml file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have a controller attribute.  You need to add a controller attribute so your view can interact with it's controller. 
 Insert `fx:controller="com.yourcompany.YourController"` before the closing the opening tag of your root element.

Example: `<AnchorPane ... fx:controller="com.yourcompany.YourController">`

Next, in your controller class, make sure that you have a function set up as follows:

```
@FXML
void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent e) {
    // Your logic goes here...
}
```

Now when you load your view via FXML, it should be able to interact with the controller class.

Comment: Probably. But how do you know the OP isn't setting the controller on the `FXMLLoader` (in which case this solution would generate a runtime exception)? There really isn't enough information in the question to know what the actual problem is, or what the correct solution is.